# Running 3-6V motors with 7.2V

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor

I'm using the popular DIY motor:
[image: DIY TT motor]

Which his operating voltage is claimed to be between 3-6V.

I'm using a battery of 7.2V. I know that running the motor outside the recommended voltage range might shorten it's lifespan. I'm planning to use it for the next couple of months, about 10 hours of total usage. Will it be safe to say that the motor will still be able withstand this voltage?

Comment: One way to find out. Do you have two of them? Why not just bring your voltage down to the specified range?

Comment: Get a cheap voltage-regulator & avoid smelling the burnt enamel when your motor's coils melt their insulation.

Comment: How is this not electronic design -___-

Answer (score 3):

No. Why should it? You're operating outside the manufacturer's ratings so you can expect it to fail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmWzQB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two-diode voltage dropper.*

Wire two silicon diodes in series with the circuit. They will drop 0.6 to 0.8 V each and run the motor at about 5.8 V.

Answer (score 2):

Over driving the motor will affect it's life by an unknown amount. It may live for a year, a month, a day, or immediately burn itself out. It also depends on how often you turn the motor on, and for how long each time. Longer periods of time mean more heat buildup.

A quick fix is to lower the voltage, through the use of two diodes in series. Standard 1n400x should be fine. At 0.7V per diode, that's 1.4 volt drop from the nominally 7.2V battery, giving you 5.8 volts at the pager motor.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any component outside of it's absolute maximum ratings. The effects are not to be underestimated.
A very common way to protect components from overvoltage is the proper use of suppressor diodes or zener diodes. They are used in all kind of devices. They are wired in parallel with the component to be protected. If the voltage applied is higher than the breakdown voltage of the suppressor diode, it will "breakdown" and conduct so that the voltage will drop and the component is protected. 
For more information [click here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html)

However, these diodes are for transient overvoltages, not continuous! So the solution would be to adjust the input voltage. Is the motor directly driven from the battery without any electronics? Then you should use at least two normal diodes in series with the motor. Watch out for the maximum current that is drawn.
You could also switch to a 5V Battery-Pack, witch are getting really common with the USB Powerbanks these days.